# why requestFocus () must be invoked after the stage is displayed

Tags: javafx, keyevent

I have write the next code to response to key-pressed

```
    circle.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
         if( e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP)
            pt.setRate(pt.getRate() +3 );

    });
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("SineWave Animation");
    primaryStage.show();
    circle.requestFocus();
```

If I write the line `circle.requestFocus();` after  `primaryStage.show();` the code works fine, but if write it before it doesn't respond to **keyEvent**.

I just research and I look that `requestFocus ()`  must be invoked after the stage is displayed.

Comment: It's expected. You are attaching the key listener to the circle, so it is only executed if the circle is focused.

Comment: could explain more ?